# Github repository is garbled, need to replace with a 'clean' version

Tags: git, github

Through some errors on my system `master` had some corrupted files that were pushed into the repository and the repository couldn't be reverted.

I have a backup folder of all of my key repository files, although when I try to add this into github it has all of the same .git info inside. I want to clear all that info from my folder and start it as a fresh repository from scratch, just uploading all the files I have as the first commit.

How can this be done? I'm on OSX and can't see any .git files or folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the solution was to just delete the `.git` folder from my directory, in terminal I simply did:

```
 $ rm -rf .git
```

Done and done!